# owl carousel width issue while screen resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, drupal

I am using owl.carousel For Making carousel in drupal site.

I have 3 boxes to show at first time and next and prev Arrows are there but JS itself adds it's width for Owl-item so,while screen resize instead of 3 boxes 4 boxes comes which overlaps on each other.

I tried giving width with `!important` but it's wrapper width is dynamic and I can't change that.

Kindly Give me solution for removing JS width or width should apply like this for screen resize boxes should not overlap and show 3 boxes.

Comment: *owl-carousel* give you the flexibility to set no of item to view, under particular screen-width, read its documentation.

Comment: ok ya I saw that but it's not getting implemented http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/responsive.html

Comment: well, unless you haven't modified its default classes, providing a **JSFiddle** will be more helpful.

Comment: I think you have to use @media instructions to make a different CSS to create a responsive carrousel instead dynamically values

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger this function every time window is resized:

```
function owlres() {
    var $carousel = $('.owl-carousel');  
    if($carousel.length>0)  {   
        $carousel.data('owl.carousel')._invalidated.width = true;
        $carousel.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
    }
}
```

For example, I have a sidebar menu that can be hidden which increases the width of the content box and mess with owlcarousel width. The button trigger:

```
$("#sidebar-toggle").on('click',function(){
            owlres();
        })
```

Source: https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/842

Answer (score 0):

Yeiii

I got the answer hope this will help any of you

```
jQuery(".owlCarousel").owlCarousel({
        navigation:true,
        itemElement:'.views-row',
        items : 3,
        itemsMobile : [768,1],
        itemsDesktop : [1500,3],
        rewindNav:false,
        navigationText: false
      });
```

Specify width according to requirement

Answer (score 0):

Init owl carousal on $(window).load() function.

```
$(window).on('load', function (){
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({...});
});
```

It fixes my problem.